# Best practice for setting default parameters in a AS3 class?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

quick question:
Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class ribbon extends Sprite {
    private var fallAmount,taper;

    public function ribbon(FallAmount=50,Taper=0.2){
        fallAmount=FallAmount;
        taper=Taper;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initial variables should have a value like displayed below and explicit strong typing is a feature of AS3 of which should never been forgotten. But aside from that - pretty sound.

k - I didn't realise this'll be a final solution - so here's some edits

- Class names are uppercase. This is the same as as3 native (e.g. `Sprite`) and it defines the use of it well:

  `var ribbon:Ribbon = new Ribbon() //See how it flows well`.
- Internal private var's can have an underscore. this denotes whilst programming an internal variable and is good for others when you share your code.

---

```
public class Ribbon extends Sprite {
    private var _fallAmount:int = 50;
    private var _taper:Number = .2;

    public function Ribbon(fallAmount:int=50, taper:Number=0.2){
        this._fallAmount = fallAmount;
        this._taper = taper;
    }
}
```

---

Hope it helps buddy.

Comment: Whats the advantage to strong typing? Is it faster? I often find it just causes more errors (I'm a very hacky programmer!). Do semicolons increase speed at all?

Comment: @cronoklee - Compiler errors are your friend.  They help identify code that could lead to runtime errors. :)

Comment: Also they're faster in certain ways. If the compiler doesn't know the type of the object it has to look up its methods and properties as it goes. This is fine in many cases, but if you're looping through multiple objects it has to do that lookup every time, for instance. Can slow you down dramatically when dealing with large amounts of information.

Comment: +1 for strong typing. It's finally here (and by finally, I mean with AS3), so let's take advantage of it. @Glycerine I'm glad you changed the arguments passed in to lowercase (which is standard) but you need to change Taper to taper in the function body.

Comment: Personally I think you should omit the `this` keyword when your using underscores for the class's properties. The `this` keyword is only really required when a local variable shadows a class property.

Comment: Interesting stuff allright. Since we're being pedantic I might as well ask about semi colons: Do they really increase speed or are they just a legacy thing from Java?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be most inclined to do this like so:

```
public class Ribbon extends Sprite
{
    private var _fallAmount:int = 50;
    private var _taper:Number = 0.2;
}
```